# How can I use regex to match a character (') when not following a specific character (?)?

Tags: c#, regex, edi, edifact

How can I write a regex pattern to split a string by a specific delimiter as long as it's not preceded by a question mark?

I've written a parser that splits an EDIFACT message into segments, composites and elements. But in the EDI standard the question mark is an escape character.
So to split this string:

```
'PRI+2.005:1+9022.5'RAD+RRHANB97+120814'
```

I can use string.Split('\''), and then string.split('+') and then string.split(':') to get PRI, 2.005, 1, 9022.5 and so on
However, these characters can be escaped by a question mark:

```
'PRI+2.005?+3.2:1+9022.5'RAD?'R+RRHANB97+120814'
```

which should now be PRI, 2.005+3.2, 1, 9022.5, RAD'R, RRHANB97.

Can someone help with a regular expression that would match the ' and not the ?'?

Thanks

Comment: You could use a negative lookbehind: `(?<!\?)'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [negative lookbehind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs):

```
(?<!\?)'
```

Comment: Thanks! I kept using (?=!\?)' Positive look ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **\'** and instead of trying to do a **regex.Matches**, do a **regex.Split** instead