# How to match a string until the first instance of a character that does not follow another specific character

Tags: php, regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

Related question: [How can I use regex to match a character (') when not following a specific character (?)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970643/how-can-i-use-regex-to-match-a-character-when-not-following-a-specific-chara)

I'm parsing a log using regex (PHP PCRE library), and trying to extract a URL from it. The URL is encapsulated in double quotes ", but some of the requests also include a double quote ". For example:

```
"https://www.amh.net.au/online/dbSearch.php?t=all&q=\"Rosuvastatin\""
```

My first pattern was basically:

```
#\"([^\"]*)\"#
```

This worked well, until I reached one of the entries as above, and it truncated the match so all I got was:

```
https://www.amh.net.au/online/dbSearch.php?t=all&q=\
```

After digging around, and rediscovering the cheatsheets for regex at http://addedbytes.com and also some more useful information at http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html  I have now tried the following look-behind:

```
#"([(?<!\\)"]*)"#
```

But, now all I get is "" and then an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLs in the logs would be URL-encoded.  As such, the following pattern should work:

```
#\"([^ ]*)\"#
```

Answer (score 2):

You placed your lookbehind INSIDE your group ([]), so it's not interpreted as such, but rather just you say you only want those individual characters.
Basically, I think you'd like something like this:

```
#"(?:[^"]|(?<=\\)")"#
```

Though you should be aware that you'd be trolled by \\" for example.